# sed error: sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command

Tags: python, sed, os.system

I am running the sed command inside python using `os.system`. Below is the code.

```
os.system("sed -i /solid/s/Visualization Toolkit generated SLA File/chestwall/g mesh1.stl")
```

The name to be changed has spaces in it. Also, in the end part i.e. `mesh1.stl`, the `1` need to be variable. How to do it?

1. Firstly, for this code, I am getting error as:

   `sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated s command`

I tried putting `/` at the end.

2. Second, I need the `mesh1` to be a variable from previous line. Say, mesh1 as `a` and everytime, `a` changes. How to write like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the sed statement/command is in either double or single quotes and then use "+" to concatenate strings before passing them to os.system

```
import os
var=1
os.system("sed -i 's/solid/s/Visualization Toolkit generated SLA File/chestwall/g' mesh" + var + ".stl")
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `os.system()` is now considered to be superseded by
`subprocess.call()`.

Would you please try the following:

```
import subprocess
a = 'mesh1'
cmd = ['sed', '-i', '/solid/s/Visualization Toolkit generated SLA File/chestwall/g', '{0}.stl'.format(a)]
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

You can pass the command as a list, not a string, and you can explicitly divide the arguments.